# What to do if an EU airline cancels your ticket without notifying you?

Tags: airlines, bookings, passenger-rights

I had bought a flight ticket with Norwegian Air for a flight on the other day, but when I arrived to the airport to do the check-in, they said they had cancelled my ticket because they didn't "have time to confirm my credit card" (besides I received the confirmation previously).

Do customers can make a complaint or are covered in any way in these situations?

*Update: I forgot to say that the refunded me full amount, but I lost time, and every reservation I had in my destination, I don't think is something fair (or serious) to do after the company confirmed the flight.

Comment: You can file a complaint; you should, especially if you received a reservation confirmation.

Comment: @pnuts will check that link thanks, the flight was from Barcelona to Tenerife, Spain.

Comment: It is also relevant exactly _which_ "Norwegian" you had a ticket with. There are three legally distinct airlines that share the Norwegian branding; one is headquartered in Ireland and therefore covered by the EU passenger rights regulations no matter where they fly; the other two are based in Norway and only covered for flights originating at an EU airport.

Comment: @Max Yes I have the reservation confirmation.

Comment: First rule of travel, log in and check your reservation from time to time.  Flights change, times changes, tickets have issues.

Comment: @HenningMakholm EU 261/2004 applies equally in Norway as in the EU countries.

Comment: @Doc: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm See Article 3 in [the Agreement Establishing the European Common Aviation Area](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:22006A1016(01):EN:PDF), to which Norway is a Contracting Party: "The applicable provisions of Acts referred to or contained either in Annex I, adapted in accordance with Annex II, or in decisions of the Joint Committee shall be binding upon the Contracting Parties and be, or be made, part of their internal legal order as follows ... " then see Annex I part G on page L285/25 where EC 261/2004 is indeed listed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You also need to read Annex II (2) which adapts the meanings of certain words found in existing regulations and legal instruments. For instance “the term ‘Community airport’ shall read ‘airport located in the European Common Aviation Area’ ” ... it is a lot quicker just to say that the Regulation covers Norway as though Norway were an EU member state.

Comment: @Calchas does it also cover Switzerland then?

Comment: If they never charged your credit card, then it's extremely likely they never actually issued a "ticket" (just a reservation).  Without a ticket, most of the conditions mentioned above/below do not apply.  Did you ever receive an actual "ticket number"?

Comment: @Doc It is already clear at the bottom of the question. I've had already purchased the ticket, they charged my credit card and few days after that they refunded the full amount of the ticket. I went to the airport with my ticket confirmation.

Answer (score 6):

> What to do if an EU airline cancels your ticket without notifying you?

If the airline provides a suitable alternative, nothing special.

If the airline does not provide a suitable alternative, buy another ticket and demand recompense.

> Do customers can make a complaint or are covered in any way in these situations?

Yes, customers may (in this case probably should) complain.

Yes, there is cover - to refund or find you alternative transport.

Airlines are never normally responsible to passengers for consequential losses – the contract is only for carriage. Insurance may however do so.